# drives or file sync between PDC and BDC at time interval

Tags: windows-server-2003, synchronization, domain-controller

I have **Windows 2003 R2 Server** installed on both **PDC** and **BDC**.

On the **D: Drive** of **PDC**, I have a folder called ***ALL_Staff*** which is mapped as **Z: Drive** and **Oracle** as **N: Drive** on the computers of all office employees. **ALL_Staff** folder has files of employees and **Oracle** folder has files to run software.

Now, I want BDC to synchronize the whole **ALL_Staff** and **Oracle** files of PDC every hour interval. As if PDC fails, without any interruption BDC act as PDC and everything works smoothly.

I have gone through the previous articles of SF, but those pointed out for freewares. Isnt there any else way.

I also noticed one thing. We can make the mapped drive **Make Available Offline** and kinda synchronize later on Windows Xp, but there is no such facility on Windows Server 2003 R2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) There is no such thing a PDC or BDC anymore.  Please stop confusing your terminology.

2) Don't use your DCs for other services.  (Like filesharing, for example.)  This causes a lot of easily avoidable headaches.

3) [Technet guide to setting up DFS on Server 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737358(v=ws.10).aspx).  Might want to set up a proper file server or two on a modern Windows Server OS and then use the guide for it, by the way.

Comment: They could stand for Philadelphia Data Center and Boston Data Center :-)

Comment: DFS-R on Windows 2008 has huge improvements over what was in 2003.  If you plan on going with DFS-R I strongly suggest you look into upgrading.

Comment: @Zoredache  This is a good point.  I'm dealing with a 2003 DFS environment, and it's a headache.  Server 2008 and DFS-R is definitely the way to go if it's an option.